# How to layout left margin and bullets using parskip

Tags: indentation, parskip, bullets

There is a  fairly typical layout style in technical manual in which headings are numbered and left justified.  The text then is indented about 1cm so that it appears as if there is a larger left margin, and the numbers from the headings extending into this margin.  I got the basic support from a package called `parskip` which gets me 95% of the way there.

I shifted the paragraphs over using `\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}`

I want to have bullets, this is the challenge.  The bullets should be slightly more indented than the paragraphs.   I succeeded in getting this by the following left margin settings (note that the top level has an extra 1cm to make it fall under the paragraph):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=1.4cm}
\setlist[itemize,2]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[itemize,3]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

the problem is that I also have boxes called "notes" which contain text, and also contain bullets.  When used in a note, I DON'T want the extra 1cm shift over.  Note in this example how the bullets are too far indented:

[image]

I need to define bullets in such a way that they work both in the main text, and the note boxes.

I am thinking there might be a better way to do this:  define the left and right margin to be the edges of the text area, and change the heading to "outdent" into that space, outside of the text area.  I am afraid my command of just how the various dimension effect other dimensions is not good enough to figure out how to do this, or even to know whether that is a good approach.  Suggestions?

I am including a complete example below, with several sections, text, and bullet sections:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,pagesize=pdftex,openright,headings=twolinechapter,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nameref}


\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Arial}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\fontspec[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{% modified example from page 83
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}


\makeindex

\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, footnotesep=.4in]{geometry}


%Page size settings
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight

%parskip gives us outdented headers with numbers, no indent on paragraphs
%and a little vertical space between paragraphs.
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}


%control whether extra vertical space is distributed between paragraphs
%either raggedbottom or flushbottom
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=purple,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{listings}


%TABLES
%make more space between lines
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textbullet}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=1.4cm}
\setlist[itemize,2]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[itemize,3]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=1.4cm}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{leftmargin=0.5cm}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}   
\colorlet{notecolor}{gray!25}

\newenvironment{note}%
   {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=notecolor,width=0.94\textwidth,left=1pt,right=1pt] Note: }%
   {\end{tcolorbox}} 


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is a chapter heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\section{Section Heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.


\subsection{Subsection Heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\item second item

\begin{itemize}

\item first nested

\item second nested

\end{itemize}

\item third item

\end{itemize}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\subsection{This is the second subsection}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\begin{note}

This is a note and below some bullets

\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\item second item

\begin{itemize}

\item first nested

\item second nested

\end{itemize}

\item third item

\end{itemize}

\end{note}


This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another (simpler?) possibility would be to make the  chapter and section title start in the left margin. This is not hard to do with package `titlesec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the indentation of itemize locally, inside the definition of `note`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,pagesize=pdftex,openright,headings=twolinechapter,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nameref}


\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Arial}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\fontspec[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{% modified example from page 83
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}


\makeindex

\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, footnotesep=.4in]{geometry}


%Page size settings
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight

%parskip gives us outdented headers with numbers, no indent on paragraphs
%and a little vertical space between paragraphs.
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}


%control whether extra vertical space is distributed between paragraphs
%either raggedbottom or flushbottom
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=purple,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{listings}


%TABLES
%make more space between lines
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textbullet}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=1.4cm}
\setlist[itemize,2]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[itemize,3]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=1.4cm}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=0.5cm}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{leftmargin=0.5cm}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\colorlet{notecolor}{gray!25}

\newenvironment{note}%
   {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=notecolor,width=0.94\textwidth,left=1pt,right=1pt]%
    \setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=.4cm}% <-- HERE
     Note: }%
   {\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is a chapter heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\section{Section Heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.


\subsection{Subsection Heading}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\item second item

\begin{itemize}

\item first nested

\item second nested

\end{itemize}

\item third item

\end{itemize}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\subsection{This is the second subsection}

This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\begin{note}

This is a note and below some bullets

\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\item second item

\begin{itemize}

\item first nested

\item second nested

\end{itemize}

\item third item

\end{itemize}

\end{note}


This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.  This is a block of normal text long enough to wrap a couple of times in the output.

\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\item second item

\begin{itemize}

\item first nested

\item second nested

\end{itemize}

\item third item

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that is one way to do it.  I little hack-ish but it works well

Comment: The clean solution would be, as @Bernard suggested, setting up proper hanging numbers for chapters, sections, etc. pp.